# How to check "eval" command?

Tags: environment-variables, docker, posix, command-substitution, eval

My code

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox dev
```

VBoxManage list vms

```
"minikube" {9c326ed5-faf4-42fe-acda-bf3a283f1a74}
"kalinew" {de6de631-0d51-4638-b967-66db463cbf05}
"dev" {84a116bf-02b9-48e3-809a-f5232518c8ee}
```

Then

```
eval "$(docker-machine env dev)"
```

My goal was to check with echo

```
echo $dev
```

Got empty line.
Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `docker-machine env dev` doesn't set the environment variable `dev`, it sets environment variables for the **host** called `dev`.

Run `docker-machine env dev` without the `eval` to see what environment variables get set. Also compare with the output of `docker-machine env` (without `dev`) if your docker-machine configuration is wrong somewhere, but still has a reasonable default.